# Why random numbers in Bayes' Net Sampling

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bayesian-networks, reasoning

I am trying to wrap my head around sampling in Bayesian Networks (simple unoptimized prior sampling for now). From what I understand, the idea is to produce a limited number of samples and see, how they propagate through the network. I do not understand, why a random number generator is necessary for this process.

Suppose you have a random variable node with a Conditional Probability Distribution (CPD) as follows:

```
| Color | P(Color) |
|------------------|
| Red   | 0.1      |
| Green | 0.2      |
| Blue  | 0.7      |
```

Then the introductions I could find say, that for each sample you want to take, you should call a **random()**-function yielding e.g. something in **[0.0, 1.0)**, and then check, into which sub-interval **Red:[0.0, 0.1)**, **Green:[0.1, 0.3)** or **Blue: [0.3, 1.0)** it falls.

My question is, why even call a random number generator? After all, you have your probabilities right in front of you. If you decide ahead of time, that you want to create an amount **n** of samples, couldn't you just have **0.1*n** samples be Red, **0.2*n** samples be Green and **0.7*n** samples be Blue? For a child node with its CPD, you could then split up all red, green and blue samples according to their respective conditional probabilities, again without using a random number generator.

This would still be an approximation, since you're still not reasoning over the complete Joint Probability Distribution. And in the limit this should still approach the correct conditional probabilities for **n --> infinity**, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The following are comments from Hernan C. Vazquez, taken from an exchange in the context of his first answer. Within this exchange, his comments answered my original question, so I thought I would post them as an answer here.*

You need random because If a sample isn't randomly selected, it will probably be biased in some way. You need to ensure that the data is representative of the population and the way to do this is through a random number generator.

In other words, you can have heads or tails with 0.5 each one. If I want to take 2 samples (n = 2), and I use 0.5 * n then I have that for each time it comes out head or tail the following is the opposite, P (head | tail) = 1 and viceversa. And that's not a representative sample since P (head | tail) = 0.5. You are changing the rules of the game.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you do not need random sampling for that. In general, if the graph is not very large, you can calculate the exact rigth answer (for example through variable elimination). However, in practice, the probabilistic models are often quite complex. Algorithms like variable elimination may be too slow for them. Sampling methods is a way to approximate algorithms, which produce answers by repeatedly generating random numbers. Consider that you could have a lot of nodes and edges and need to calculate the probability across them to answer for example, P(Color=blue, NodeB=value1, ... and so on). That solution can be an exponential-time calculation (depending on the size of the network).

Why random number generation in sampling? You need random because If a sample isn't randomly selected, it will probably be biased in some way. You need to ensure that the data is representative of the population and the way to do this is through a random number generator.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand, that exact methods like variable elimination are NP-hard. However, my question is about the numerical/approximate approach behind sampling. I am unclear, why _in the sampling method_ you would need a random number generator.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry if I did not understand you. You need random because If a sample isn't randomly selected, it will probably be biased in some way. You need to ensure that the data is representative of the population and the way to do this is through a random number generator.

Comment: In other words, you can have heads or tails with 0.5 each one. If I want to take 2 samples (n = 2), and I use 0.5 * n then I have that for each time it comes out head or tail the following is the opposite, P (head | tail) = 1 and viceversa. And that's not a representative sample since P (head | tail) = 0.5. You are changing the rules of the game.